# How does git auto-merge changes in the same file when they are not in the same line?

Tags: git, git-merge

I read in various sites that git auto-merges changes to the same file when they are not in the same line.
For example:

--Base file--

```
line 1:   int a = 3;
line 2:   b = 4 + 4;
```

--Local edition-- (added new line)

```
line 1    int a = 3;
line 2    b = 4 + 4;
line 3    c = a + b;
```

--Remote edition-- (deleted "int a = 3")

```
line 1       
line 2    b = 4 + 4;
line 3
```

What happens if I commit the changes in the local file and then I do "git pull" from the remote? Local edition added a line, and remote edition deleted a line, but there weren't any changes in the same lines. Does git delete "int a = 3" (which is being used in the added line of the local edition)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072888/does-git-merge-complete-files-or-changed-portions-of-it/26075025#26075025

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried doing this, merging what I call in the question 'local' branch with 'remote' branch and yes, git deletes the first line and this is the result

```
line 1: 
line 2:   b = 5 + 5;
line 3:   c = a + 2;
```